# Regular expression for dataframe column

Tags: python, regex

I would like to take out only the date part of my dataframe column which has data like

```
$83,00010/7/2016       10/7/2016  # is the date here
$721,0002/7/2015       2/7/2015  # is the date here
$3,00012/12/2015       12/12/2015  # is the date here
```

I tried patterns like

```
^(?!,\d{3}) and (\$[,\d{3}]*\,\d{3})
```

but I am not able to exactly pick just the date part.

Comment: Is the format month/day/year or day/month/year?

Comment: @Karthik Is it 02 or just 2? How would you know?

Comment: The month part has no fixed format. It can be 2 in some places and 02 in others. The only thing we know for sure is it starts after the comma followed by 3 digits which denotes the end of currency.

Comment: And the format is month/day/year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is slightly complicated, let's start with a simple expression, then we would expand it. I'm hoping that we would have `,` in our money part, then we might try:

```
,\d{3}(\d{1,2}\/.+?\/\d{4})
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lM8OgL/1/)

or

```
([1-3]?\d\/.+?\/\d{4})
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aH3mCi/1/)

#### Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"([1-3]?\d\/.+?\/\d{4})"

test_str = ("$83,00010/7/2016 ----> 10/7/2016 is the date here,\n"
    "$721,0002/7/2015 ----> 2/7/2015 is the date here,\n"
    "$3,00012/12/2015  -----> 12/12/2015 is the date here")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following regex will return you the date:

```
',\d{3}(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4})$'
```